# How do I access a collection from more than one file in Meteorjs?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my main js file I have defined a "new Meteor.Collection("Decks")" and I populate some data if there is no data.

Now I have a views folder in the client folder that has the javascript for events of the templates. Each template has it's own js file. Those events need to query and update the Decks collection, but I have no idea how I would do that. I tried writing a "new Meteor.Collection("Decks")" in the event code, but I got an error that the collection already exists.

I could imagine using requirejs to pass along a global variable to the events perhaps, but I feel there must be a native way to do it in Meteor.

How do I access the same collection in a different file?

As an example, my app is called "builder", so the main js is called "builder.js" and contains:

```
var Decks = new Meteor.Collection("Decks");
```

Then I have another javascript file called "do_other_stuff.js" in the client folder and it wants to query the Decks collection, so something like:

```
var first_deck = Decks.findOne({name: "first"});
```

But obviously that won't work, because Decks is not a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, make `Decks` a global variable! Remove the `var` keyword:

```
Decks = new Meteor.Collection("Decks");
```

Comment: Oh, I thought, because the window object is inaccessible, that I wouldn't be able to access global variables, but after trying it I see they are still accessible, you simply don't use the window object to access them. Very scary to do this, so I'll have to transition to a better way like require...

I dunno... I feel like Meteor should have something for this, so people don't have to use requirejs to keep their code clean.

I'm going to wait another day for a better answer, then mark yours as correct if I don't get one. You definitely gave me a working answer :). Thanks.

Comment: Don't be scared, that's how it's done! This alone won't cause your code to be messy, while trying to use require.js with Meteor can! (I've seen that, it was terrible.) Also, the `window` object is perfectly accessible. Just make sure you don't try to use it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.subscribe("Decks")` in the file should do the trick.

Comment: Have voted it up to cancel out your negative vote. Ensuring you have published and subscribed to your collections (when not using meteor's autopublish package) using Meteor.subscribe() and Meteor.publish() on the client and server respectively is likely to be the cause of other users Collection.find() errors.