# Meteor cannot access collection created in server/main.js

Tags: meteor

I defined the collection in lib/collection.js

```
var Tags = new Meteor.Collection("Tags");
```

Then trying to initialize it in server/main.js:

```
Tags.insert({name: tag["tag"], default_show: true});
```

Got error:
W20141028-01:26:53.647(11)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Tags is not defined
W20141028-01:26:53.648(11)? (STDERR)     at app/server/main.js:43:18

I cannot figure out why I got error here? Anyone could give me some hints?

Full source code:

server/main.js

```
Meteor.startup(function() {    
    var tagsJson =  JSON.parse(Assets.getText("tags.json"));
    var tagsMapJson = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("tags_map.json"));

    tagsJson["lines"].map(function(line) {
        line["tags"].map(function(tag){
            if (!Tags.findOne({name: tag["tag"]})) {
                Tags.insert({name: tag["tag"], default_show: true});
            }

            tagsMapJson[tag["tag"]].map(function(web) {
                if (!Webs.findOne({url: web["url"]})) {
                    Webs.insert({url: web["url"], name: web["name"], brief: web["brief"]});
                }

                if (!TagWebs.findOne({tag: tag["tag"], url: web["url"]})) {
                    TagWebs.insert({tag: tag["tag"], url: web["url"]});
                }
            });
        });
    });        
});
```

lib/collections.js

```
var Tags = new Meteor.Collection("Tags");
var Webs = new Meteor.Collection("Webs");
var TagWebs = new Meteor.Collection("TagWebs");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access a collection from more than one file in Meteorjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354549/how-do-i-access-a-collection-from-more-than-one-file-in-meteorjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should erase "var" so collection is seen to whole project

Comment: This answer is correct but I think a little more explanation is required. JavaScript has two types of variable definitions. Global variables (can be used anywhere within the application are created without the var prefix where local (current file only) variables are created with a var prefix.

Comment: Yeah, but I wasn't sure about it so I didn't want to spread heresy ;p Basically what I do is if some variable won't work properly make it global and see if problem stays.